# Asus K55VM usb 3.0 issue

Tags: windows-7, usb, asus-laptop

I own an Asus K55VM laptop and I found out that there are some unknown and unusual issues with usb 3.0 ports. I haven't noticed anything strange until now. I got a new Toshiba USB 3.0 external hdd and when I try to copy larger amount of data from my disk to the external hdd, the OS(windows 7) randomly starts ignoring the external hdd. It doesn't shut it down, it kinda just stops responding but the light on the hdd is still lit. I get an error that the files cannot be copied.

I have reinstalled windows 7, installed all drivers(including intel chipset drivers of course) and the issue is still present. It acts normal when copying small amount of data. Also, I heard that some intel chipsets have an issue with usb, something about the connectors not transferring power when the usb device enters some kind of "low power mode" causing the device to stop responding and you need to plug it out and in again. But the thing is, my Intel® Chief River Chipset HM76 is not on the list of affected hardware(not ENTIRELY sure though).

If anyone has any idea of what the problem to this might be, I'd be greatful.

Edit: The hdd works perfectly fine even for large amounts of data if plugged in the usb 2.0 port!

Comment: you should make sure your usb 3.0 drivers are correctly installed. check your manufacturer's website and take preference for manufacturer drivers.

Comment: I should have mentioned I'm not a tech-retard. My usb 3.0 drivers are correctly installed, downloaded from my manufacturers website and are exactly for my model. So the issue is most likely not driver related.

Comment: never did i say you were retard. as you know, when troubleshooting always exclude the most obvious possibilities.

Comment: I agree, but just to let everybody else know and to also exclude answers like "did you try turning it off and on again?" :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop, with a Transcend HDD. I get a similar, if not the same, problem, too. In my case, the issue is file-size agnostic. But, for me it is a problem with the data cable being a loose fit. Even then, connecting the drive to the USB2.0 port improves things a lot. I suspect it is an issue with the physical or firmware-level configuration of the port itself, as I have faced similar issues with other HDDs, even a SONY one, all the way up to BSODs. You could try updating your BIOS version, that helped me.